# pasar codigo de matlab a python

Tags: python, matlab

Tengo estos codigos en matlab:

```
clear all;
xmin=input (' minimo=');
xmax=input ('maximo=');
res=0.5;
ymin=0;
ymax=1;
b=input('centro=');
a=input('inicio=');
ejex=xmin:res:xmax;
i=1;
for x=ejex;
    if (x<a)
        pertenhombroder(i)=0;

    end
    if (x>=a)&(x<b)
        pertenhombroder(i)=(x-a)/(b-a);
    end
    if (x>=b)
        pertenhombroder(i)=1;
    end
    i=i+1;
end
plot(ejex,pertenhombroder)
title('Funcion de pertenencia hombro derecho');
axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]);
ylabel('Grado de pertenencia');
///////////////////////////////////
clear all;
xmin=input (' minimo=');
xmax=input ('maximo=');
res=0.5;
ymin=0;
ymax=1;
b=input('fin=');
a=input('centro=');

ejex=xmin:res:xmax;
i=1;

for x=ejex;
    if (x<a)
        pertenhombroizq (i)=1;
    end
    if (x>=a)&(x<b)
        pertenhombroizq (i)=1-(x-a)/(b-a);
    end
    if (x>=b)
        pertenhombroizq(i)=0;
    end
    i=i+1;
end
plot(ejex,pertenhombroizq)
title('Funcion de pertenencia hombro izquierdo');
axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax]);
ylabel('Grado de pertenencia');
```

me gustaria que me ayudaran a pasarlos a lenguaje de python ya que el primero me quedo asi:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmin=int(input("Minimo="))
xmax=int(input("Maximo="))
res=0.5;
ymin=0;
ymax=1;
b=int(input("Centro="))
a=int(input("Inicio="))
ejex=xmin or res or xmax
i=1
acum=0

for x in range(ejex):
    if x<a:
        phd=acum+1+0
    elif x>=a or x<b:
        phd=acum+i+(x-a/b-a)
    elif x>=b:
        phd=acum+i+1

    i=i+1
datos=np.arange(ejex,phd)
datos=np.radians(datos)
datos2=plt.axis([ymin,ymax, xmin ,phd])
plt.plot(datos2,'b--')
ax=plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
ax.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
plt.show()
print(phd)
```

pero no sale lo que yo quiero y me han dicho que el problema son las funciones que estan en los if en los codigos de matlab

Comment: Igual mejoras tus posibilidades de obtener una respuesta si en lugar de pedir que alguien traduzca tu código matlab a python (lo que implica que quien responda debe conocer ambos lenguajes), simplemente dices qué quieres hacer (o sea, qué se supone que hace el código matlab), pues quien responda en este caso sólo necesita conocer python

Comment: Lo que quiero es que en python graficar logica difusa , en este caso hombro derecho y hombro izquierdo

Answer (score 2):

Aunque no conozco el lenguaje Matlab ni la lógica difusa, leyendo el código y tratando de adivinar, creo que al final lo que quieres es graficar un par de funciones, a las que llamas "pertenencia al hombro izquierdo" y "pertenencia al hombro de derecho".

Ambas son funciones similares, formadas por tres tramos. Uno horizontal para `x<a`, con valor `1` para el hombro izquierdo y `0` para el derecho. Otro, también en horizontal para `x>=b`, con valor `0` para el hombro izquierdo y `1` para el derecho. Y finalmente un tramo intermedio para las `x` entre `a` y `b`, que va en diagonal uniendo los dos tramos horizontales anteriores.

Para generar estas funciones es necesario ir dando valores a `x`, cosa que haces entre `xmin` y `xmax` a incrementos de `res`, y para cada `x` evalúas la función antes descrita. Lo que tienes que hacer es ir guardando estos valores resultantes en una lista, en lugar de ir sumándolas a un número.

Finalmente a `plt.plot()` tienes que pasarle la lista con las `x` y la lista con las `y`.

El siguiente código hace todo esto, mostrando al final ambas funciones en un solo plot, con las leyendas y títulos adecuados. He cambiado los inputs del principio por unas asignaciones de unos valores de muestra:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xmin=0
xmax=10
res=0.5

b = centro = 6
a = inicio = 2

# Generemos la lista de las posibles x
xrange = np.arange(xmin, xmax, res)

perten_hombro_dcho = []   # Lista para guardar los valores de una función
perten_hombro_izdo = []   # y otra lista para los valores de la otra función

# Recorriendo la lista de las posibles x, calculamos cada valor y lo
# guardamos en la lista de la función correspondiente
for x in xrange:
    if x<a:
        perten_hombro_dcho.append(0)  # .append añade el dato a la lista
        perten_hombro_izdo.append(1)
    elif x>=a and x<b:
        perten_hombro_dcho.append((x-a)/(b-a))
        perten_hombro_izdo.append(1-(x-a)/(b-a))
    elif x>=b:
        perten_hombro_dcho.append(1)
        perten_hombro_izdo.append(0)

# Pintamos ambas funciones. Para ambas la lista de x es la misma
# pero cambiamos la lista de los valores y
# Pintamos cada una de un color diferente y le damos una etiqueta diferente
plt.plot(xrange, perten_hombro_dcho,'b--', label="Hombro derecho")
plt.plot(xrange, perten_hombro_izdo,'r--', label="Hombro izquierdo")

# Etiquetamos los ejes y la gráfica
plt.title("Funciones de pertenencia a los hombros")
plt.xlabel("Distancia al origen")
plt.ylabel("Grado de pertenencia")

# Mostramos la leyenda que relaciona colores con funciones
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]